# Mac Numbers - how to copy multiline text without quotes

Tags: numbers

When I copy a cell that has multiline content, and paste elsewhere, Numbers puts quotes around it.

How do I paste without quotes, I want to paste multiple line, as it is seen in the cell.

Comment: Hi guesty, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/293240/edit) your question to clarify it somewhat? Perhaps adding a screenshot to show what you mean by *a cell that has multiline content* would be useful in ensuring you get relevant answers.

Comment: I'm seriously considering writing an alfred workflow for this, driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste without formatting.

Comment: Quotes are added to the text on Copy so unfortunately this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Numbers:

Double-click in the cell with multiline text so that you have a text cursor blinking in the cell text.

Drag to select the text or press Command-A to select all the text

Copy the text

When you paste the text in some other program, it won't have the double quotes.